# Creating two versions of record on create in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a database for recipes and when a new recipe is created I want to create two versions of it (an original version that cant be edited) and another version that is editable.  That way users can compare the current version to the original.

I have two fields to associate them and identify them (is_original:boolean and original_id:integer)

I cant figure out where to put the code to both adjust the parameters and create the recipe twice.  I want to create the first one with is_original set to true and on original_id.  Then I need to get the id from the just created recipe and set the original_id in the next one to match.

Comment: I know this isn't what you were asking for, but would you consider using something like the `audited` gem? We use it in order to track historical changes in our records and in this case the original "snap shot" would be the first "audit" created. Just throwing that out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an after_create callback.

Also why bother with an is_original field when you can just have null for original_id. Just make an is_original? method that looks at the original_id field that returns true if null.

Comment: cause I was up late when I was creating the database structure and didnt think about that so will adjust that in my structure.  So new to rails and having trouble figuring out what to put in the callback method to get the second one created

Comment: Use self in the callback for the original, and new to create a YourClass.new to create a new record. Transfer props manually or make a clone (new_record = old_record.dup)

Comment: ok so I got the after_create method to work when testing it to change attributes...however i cant get it to create a new record, this is what I tried: new_recipe = self.dup     new_recipe.original_id=self.id        new_recipe.save

Answer (score 0):

Create the original first.  After it's created and if it's edited - create the editable version.  All edits could just create a child of the original and a basic versioning system would be in place.

Don't create two objects at once - the second is just a duplicate of the first.  That just doesn't seem necessary, especially if it's never edited.

I agree with @pixelearth on the boolean.  Use a parent_id or original_id.